# What is the meaning of this chess opening theory table?

Tags: opening

On this [example chess opening theory table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_opening_theory_table), what does "Σ%" and the number before it mean?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to paste a link?

Comment: +1 @Sam Hocevar: Oops, I mean the internet ate the link, it's back now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example given, the opening move was Nf3. A number of the main lines were given, eight more moves for Black, seven more moves for White. Then the percentages of games won by White (in tournaments) using the respective lines were tallied.

Here's a link to the table:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_opening_theory_table

Comment: Thank you for adding a better answer. Only thing that might improve it would be to take a screen grab of the table on Wiki, and crop the pic to show just the data you're referencing in your answer; doing so would make the answer easy to read, and insure if the table disappears/changes that you're answer still makes sense. Again, thank you!

Comment: @blunders: done.

Answer (score 3):

The two figures in the “Σ%” column are the number of games referenced in the database (so “Σ” should be understood in its mathematical meaning, “total” or “sum”) and the percentage of games won by White.